# Better performance in tree walkthrough

Tags: vb.net, performance, oop, tree

I'm trying to walkthrough one tree and copy it to another tree. Here is my code:

```
Public Shared Function GetConstGroupsByVehicleId(ByVal groups As Entities.ListQuickGroups) As List(Of IDC.ConstGroupNode)
    Dim node As New IDC.ConstGroupNode
    node.ChildNodes.Add(ProccessTreeChildRows(groups.row(0)))

    Return node
End Function

Public Shared Function ProccessTreeChildRows(ByVal row As Entities.t_row) As IDCLaximo.ConstGroupNode
    Dim node As New IDC.ConstGroupNode
    node.Name = row.name

    For Each item As Entities.t_row In row.row
        Try
            node.ChildNodes.Add(ProccessTreeChildRows(item))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next

    Return node
End Function
```

This works but problem is how moch time it consumes. Is there any way how to optimize this code to better performance?

Comment: What kind of tree are you trying to populate? It doesn't look like its a  'normal' treeview control that is built into .Net.

Comment: Why are you using "Try, Catch" before adding the child nodes? Try, Catch degrades performance